# Problems on continous random variable, probability, estimates.

Tags: probability, continuity, maximum-likelihood

Problem image:

[image]
answering to questions (i) and (ii) i found that:
$$pdf: f(x) = x \frac{2}{\theta^2}$$
$$E(x) = \frac{2}{3} \theta$$
$$Var(x) = \frac{1}{18}\theta^2$$

And now I tried to answer questions (iii) , (iv) and (v). My solutions:

(iii):

$E(Y) = E(X^3) = \int_{0}^\theta x^3* f(x) dx = \int_{0}^\theta x^3* (x* \frac{2}{\theta^2}) dx$ ,

$\frac{2}{\theta^2}$ is constant so:

$E(X^3) = \frac{2}{\theta^2} * \int_{0}^\theta x^4 dx = \frac{2}{\theta^2}*\frac{\theta^5}{5} = \frac{2}{5}\theta^3$

(iv):

probability to draw one random sample that is less than $\frac{2}{\theta}$ :

$P(X<\frac{2}{\theta}) = \int_{0}^\frac{2}{\theta} x* \frac{2}{\theta^2} dx =  \frac{2}{\theta^2} \int_{0}^\frac{2}{\theta} x dx = \frac{2}{\theta^2} * \frac{\theta^2}{8} = \frac{1}{4} $

probability to draw 3  independant sample less than $\frac{\theta}{2}$ :

$\frac{1}{4}^3 = \frac{1}{64}$

(v):

estimate of mean: $\frac{4.1+6.6+7.2+8.9+10}{5} = 7.36$

we know that $E(x) = \frac{2}{3}*\theta$

hence, estimate of $\theta$:

$\frac{2}{3}\theta = 7.36$

$\theta = 11.04$

QUESTION:

Are my calculations correct? If no, what am I doing wrong? What correct solutions should look like?

Comment: (iii) and (iv) look OK. In (iv) there is a typo, you write $2/\theta$ where you mean $\theta/2$, but the answer is fine. In (v) you have not set up a likelihood function.